# Text on Curve doesn't work right

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves, text-object

I want to align Text to a Curve using the "Text on Curve" option. The strange thing is that it worked on one curve but not one a different one that is the same but rotated 180°.

[image]

As you can see does the upper Text work but the lower one seams to be bugged or something. I tried it with a different Text and Curve (same shape) but it always looks like the one on the picture.

You can download the .blend file here:
[image]

Comment: You need your rotation to be correct. Likely you have a non-applied rotation or some similar problem...

Comment: @pycoder I checked and all rotations have been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pycoder is right. You have different rotations on the curve and text object.
To double check the rotations, check **Axis** under **Display** in the **Object** context in the **Properties** area.
Select all objects, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> click on the Axis checkbox, to change the property of all objects at once.

[image: show axis]

The axis will be displayed in the 3D viewport. Notice, how the lower curve is oriented different than all other objects.

[image: axis shown in 3d view]

The Bottom curve has (0, 0, 0) rotations (image above), but all other curves have different rotations.

[image: rotated objects]

If we zero out the rotations (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), the behaviour of the *Text On Curve* is now obvious.

[image: zero out rotations]

#### Step by step solution

Since we can't apply the rotation of the text. We will have to recreate the curve with the text's orientation.

1. Duplicate the curve.
2. Select the text, Shift select the curve, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and select Copy Rotation. We now added a copy rotation constraint to the duplicate curve. They have the same orientation.
3. Select the duplicated oriented curve and make its visual transform real. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Visual Transform)
4. Remove the constraint.
5. Delete the (wrong) vertices of the correctly oriented duplicate curve.
6. Select the curve, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the duplicate curve and join them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).
7. Apply the *text on curve* property.

[image: no description]

Comment: Or duplicate the original curve, mirror it by Z axis, apply scale for it and set the *Text On Curve* for the bottom text.

Comment: @MrZak I explained a more general solution, which would work with different rotations as well. In this case your approach is the easiest and fastest. Should I add this to the answer?

Comment: Use that as you wish.